# Visual Studio Code not opening in mac catalina

Tags: visual-studio-code

yesterday I have installed a theme named SynthWave '84, and I will do some setting in vs code launch.json file.
but after 2-3 hours I have changed my theme to default visual studio code theme.
till there is no problem faced.

but today when I tried to open my vs code. it will not opened. then I have deleted that from the application folder and again download the fresh copy and move that to the application folder and tried to open. but it will not be opened.